# Map not updating when using slam_toolbox in ROS2 Galactic

Tags: gazebo, ros2, slam, turtlebot3, nav2

I am currently learning mapping(slam_toolbox) and navigation(nav2) in ROS2 Galactic, using the gazebo turtlebot3 simulation. In specific, I am trying to implement lifelong mapping for my turtlebot3 simulation.

I've added objects to the gazebo map and have removed them dynamically but the map takes too long to update, when I run SLAM and nav2 simultaneously. A similar question was asked previously [in this post.](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23356/slam-toolbox-mapping-is-not-life-long) I am now able to understand why this happens, but am unaware of any solutions to fix this.

I have gone through the config and launch files but couldn't find any parameter that provides hit/miss ratio control.

I apologize if this comes off as a newbie question, I've tried searching online for existing solutions but couldn't find any.